# MongoDB Shell: Query BinData by Type

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query a large collection by the _id field which uses BinData.

Some of these ids use BinData of type 4:

```
"_id" : BinData(4,"CNDF66qIlCY92q1vFAAAAQ==")
```

While some use BinData of type 3:

```
"_id" : BinData(3,"CNDF66qJ29g92q1vFAAAEw==")
```

I need to find all of the _id fields that have BinData.type = 3 and was wondering if anyone has had luck querying like this in the MongoDB shell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) style query as the `BinData` object has a `.subtype()` method that returns that "type":

```
db.collection.find(function(){ return this._id.subtype() == 3 })
```

Note that the "type" 3 BinData is by default what would be generated by the new [UUID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/UUID/) helper available to the shell from MongoDB 2.6:

```
UUID("0123456789abcdeffedcba9876543210")
BinData(3,"ASNFZ4mrze/+3LqYdlQyEA==")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the exact reason, but in my case, the return type was a `Binary`, not a `BinData`, so, I had to use the `sub_type` property instead of the `subtype()` function, as per [@Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn)'s answer, which took me a while to figure out.